# Javascript - reformat date string to ISO8601

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp, iso8601

I have a string like this:

```
21.03.2016 23:59
```

And I need this string converted into a ISO-8601 date-time string:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00
```

Is there a simple way to convert this date?
I try it whit moment.js but i can't find a function to parse an existing date.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with jQuery. The original string has no time zone, converting it to a string that does creates an accuracy that was not available in the original, so could be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this without using moment.js.
**Look code as following:**

```
(new Date("03.21.2016 23:59")).toISOString()
```

just you need to change your string 21.03.2016 23:59 ***(dd-mm-yyyy)*** to 03.21.2016 23:59 ***(mm-dd-yyyy)***. You can easily do this by split the date and change the order of split part.

And if you dont want to do this then simply use moment.js as per matthias's answer.

Comment: No, don't do that. Parsing of "03.21.2016 23:59" is entirely implementation dependent and not required to be parsed by the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent) at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using *moment.js* you could do:

```
var dateString = '21.03.2016 23:59';
var momentDate = moment(dateString, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
console.log(momentDate.toISOString());
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyrqj1pp/2/) showing this.