# Typescript date formatting

Tags: typescript

I am using angular 2/4
 How can i format the date into this
2017-10-03T14:51:06.078Z

here is my code below :

```
  public today: number = Date.now();
 console.log("today time " +this.today);
```

I tried to add

```
this.today.toLocaleString()
```

that didn't seem to work

Comment: That question doesn't depend on Typescript since any valid JavaScript can be used in TypeScript. You are probably looking for `toISOString`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - reformat date string to ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126436/javascript-reformat-date-string-to-iso8601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the toISOString method:

```
this.today.toISOString();
```

But you need to change the type from number to Date:

```
namespace Testing {
    export class Test {
        public today: Date;

        constructor() {
            this.today = new Date();
            console.log(this.today.toISOString());
        }
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: I tried  your code it didnt work  console.log("today time " +this.today.toISOString());  I get error

Comment: Did you make today of the right type? And what compile error do you get?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this something like

```
this.todayDate = new Date();
this.dateToday = (this.todayDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ((this.todayDate.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + this.todayDate.getDate() + ' ' +this.todayDate.getHours() + ':' + this.todayDate.getMinutes()+ ':' + this.todayDate.getSeconds());
```

You can check with console log,

```
console.log('today date', this.dateToday);
```

The output will be

```
today date 2017-10-3 10:38:10
```

Explaination:
"this.dateToday" is a variable of type any which will store the date as you want.

You need to get individual year, month, date and the time as well and concat it together. 
There are many more date methods you can check online or in your IDE.